# Android: ListView

Tags: android

Need some help !
I have a ListActivity...on itch row i have 4 textVIew...

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Some.class);
    intent.putExtra(KEY, (int) id);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}
```

On list item click i can send ID easy. 
But also i have on click method on every textView...
How can i get row id when i clik on TextView of this row ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5340289/how-to-make-an-imageview-clickable-in-an-listview/5340518#5340518)

Comment: first try it jim, it going to give you id of row