# Only first row's views(button) are clickable in custom list view, android

Tags: android, android-listview

Here is my adapter class:-

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        Context c;

        CustomAdapter(Context c)
        {
            this.c=c;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return arg0;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final int pos=position;
            LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(c);
            View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_list_item, parent, false);
            ImageButton image_button=v.findViewById(R.id.imagebutton);
            image_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(c, "Image Button clicked:" + pos, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            return v;
        }

    }
```

How do I make all imagebuttons clickable? I tried searching for answers and as per an answer given here: [how to make an imageview clickable in an listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5340289/how-to-make-an-imageview-clickable-in-an-listview) I tried but only my first row button is clickable. Please help.

Comment: you should use viewholder class as per doc "The World of ListView-2010" by Romain Guy.

Comment: NewOverHere did you try my answer? does it work?

Comment: It's a 1 hour long video, still watching it now. Thanks for helping. I'll get back to you when I finish watching it and find a solution. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

In your custom adapter constructor

```
    LayoutInflater mInflater;  
    CustomAdapter(Context c)
    {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(c); 
        // initialize inflater in the constructor.
        // need not initialize everytime getView is called.
    }
```

Use a View Holder

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

```
      static class ViewHolder
       {
           ImageButton ib;
       }
      @Override
      public View getView(int position, View item, ViewGroup parent) { 
       ViewHolder holder; 
       if(item == null){
       item = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.elementos_lista_temas, null);
       holder = new ViewHolder(); 
       holder.ib = (ImageButton) item.findViewById(R.id.imagebutton);
       item.setTag(holder);
       }
       else{
        holder = (ViewHolder)item.getTag();
       }
       return item;
       }
```

Then in your activity class

```
 ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
 CustomAdapter cus = new CustomAdapter(this);
 lv.setAdapter(cus); 
 lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View itemView, int itemPosition, long itemId)
    {           
         Toast.makeText(ActivityName.this, "Image Button clicked:" + itemPosition, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    });
```

Comment: but I want to change image resource of the image button when its clicked. So how do I access my imagebutton to call image_button.setImageResource(drawable)?

Comment: In the video also they mentioned this ViewHolder class but so far they havent told how to access views on click event. Still watching...

Comment: why don't you give the above a try?

Comment: @NewOverHere That `itemView` in OnItemClick is the View you returned in your adapter. You could use `itemView.findViewById(R.id.imagebutton)` to get the `ImageButton` and then change the image from there.

Answer (score 1):

As told by "**the World of Listview-2010**" see below link show **how to use viewholder class** with **custom listview** in android http://impressive-artworx.de/2011/list-all-installed-apps/ Hope this helps you.